# Git add merge point to the past

Tags: git, branch, git-rewrite-history

Recently we started to use Git instead of CVS. We have "develop" and "release" branches. Few days ago, colleague should create release - it means merge changes from develop branch to the release branch.

But he did not use merge command, instead of it, he manually updated all modified files in release branch (these which were modified in develop branch since last release) and made ordinary commit/push (i would call it "fake-merge").

As a result I do not see the "merge point" in the branch graph.
Now when trying to merge few commits from hotfix branch (hotfix was created from develop branch) to release branch, Git wants to push all 1000+ commits since last release, although in reality the release branch has all these changes.

Since the fake-merge commit, there are few newer commits on release branch and lot of commits on develop branch.

How to solve this? Is it possible to "add the merge back in time" somehow?

Edit:

```
X--D1--D2--...--D1000--DD1--DD2--...---DD10-- ...  -- ... -- DD20 (develop branch)
 \                 "\"                     \               \ /
  \                 "\" fake-merge          -hotfix--H1--H2-H3
   \                 "\"                                     \
    -R1----------------R2-----------R3-----------------------R4 (release branch)
```

In R2 commit are included all changes from D1 to D1000, but in git graph the connection line between D1000 and R2 is missing, because programmer changes all files manually (as he was used to do that way in cvs) and did not use git merge.

When I tried to create R4, I realized that there is missing merge - connection of D1000 and R2 in git graph, because git is now going to push all D1--D1000-DD10-H3 commits.

Comment: I can't see your exact workflow here, so I'm not sure exactly what you are doing.  I don't see any reason why you couldn't just merge master into the hotfix branch, then vice-versa.  I don't understand the part about `Git wants to push all 1000+ commits since the last release`.

Comment: It would definitely clarify things if you quoted *exact commands* (and some of their output as appropriate to make it clear what is happening and what you'd like instead). See [ask].

Comment: I have updated the question with a graph to make it more precise.